# How do I create AnyPoint Studio connector designer controls?

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I am using DevKit to create a component for Anypoint Studio.  I would like to create some complex configuration controls on the designer page but I can't figure out how to add those.  I don't want the configuration to occur on the popup "Connector Configuration" dialog because that creates a global config and I need each component configured individually.  Attached is a picture of the FTP designer page to show clearly what I'm talking about.

What do I need to implement in order to create these controls?

[image: FTP Designer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to make properties like that, I make a method in the Connector class and annotate it with the @Processor Annotations e.g

```
   @Processor(friendlyName="delete")
   public List<String> deleteFiles(String hostName, String userName, String password, String path, String port){        
   }
```

The Downside of this is that you get an operation property in your connector but when you select an operation the params of that operation is shown. And you have to code it so that these are properties is overriding
those of the global configuration

Here is how the above code would look like when you use the connector

[image]

Hope this helps

Best regards

Jack